# Personal research journal/notes - an electronic solution?

Tags: research-process, online-resource, note-taking

Is anyone perhaps aware of an application, or ideally a website (always accessible) to keep track of personal notes on ones research?

This would be similar to a physical personal research journal (e.g. a simple hardcover book with ones notes), but in electronic format. I'm looking for something a bit more structured and standardised than an MS Word or Excel document, although if there's no alternative, that will have to do.